# Will Samsung EVO 860 work if WD green work on my laptop?

Tags: hard-drive, memory, ssd, sata, m.2

My system is Acer e5-575-59fd (Core i5 7th Gen 7200u CPU, Intel HD Graphics 620) which I'm trying to upgrade from HDD to SSD and it supports WD Green (m.2 SATA 2280) as I saw a video of it. I want to know will my machine support Samsung Evo 860 also if it supports WD green, as the Acer customer support says they can't provide any specific info which one will work but an m.2 SATA 6gb/s up to 256gb will while another executive said it supports up to 512gb but I'm going with lower capacity to be on safer side. I believe they both have same M.2 keying but are there any internal implementations that may make any differences in terms of compatibility?

Response from Acer customer support:
[image: Response from customer support]

I read Samsung Evo 860 has better performance than WD Green and I want to have it instead of WD Green based on that.

I use my system for programming and back-end development with multiple instances of intellij, Tomcat servers, Android Studio, multiple browsers with multiple tabs, postman etc. With this I saw the CPU is used around 50% but disk is 99-100% (only when all these are running) and RAM 85%+ which is why I'm thinking of upgrading both HDD to SSD and RAM from 8gb to 16/24gb.

Also the installed RAM is ADATA DDR4-2400MHz, my CPU supports 2133MHz. There are very less options in finding 2400MHz RAM, and If I buy one 8/16GB 2666MHz are those compatible to work together or I should stick with another 2400 only. (I'll probably ask another question regarding it as it's off topic from main question)

If you have any more suggestions I'll be very happy to hear.

This is how the slot looks like on motherboard:
[image: This is how the slot looks like on motherboard]

Here are the links to these SSDs.

WD Green:
[Western Digital WD Green m.2 SSD, 545MB/s R, 3 Y Warranty, 240GB (WDS240G2G0B)](https://www.amazon.in/dp/B078WYS5K6/ref=cm_sw_r_sms_apa_glt_i_5E16WHK86R4SB8TM772X?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1)

Samsung Evo 860:
[Samsung 860 EVO 250GB SATA M.2 (2280) Internal Solid State Drive (SSD) (MZ-N6E250)](https://www.amazon.in/dp/B07864V6CK/ref=cm_sw_r_sms_apa_glt_i_CPSZ9HG9PG75M1WZ5747?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1)

Comment: You're asking questions about a HW compatibility of an Acer laptop. I'm sorry to say but SU is not the right place to get this kind of advice. [Acer user community](https://community.acer.com/en/) is.

Comment: @Peregrino69 I tried there first, and mentioned what I received in response from customer care as well. After asking at different relevant places I'm here.

Comment: @Peregrino69 And honestly it's not acer specific but ssd type specific. "If a machine support WD Green will it support Samsung 860 or there are any differences in their internal implementation that may make a difference" to be precise. I gave information about my system just so it's easy for people to know the hardware I'm using instead of asking about it later.

Comment: The customer support was copying specifications without understanding anything about computers (I.e from a script). If your laptop supports M.2 SATA  drives it will support any size.

Comment: @Ramhound Thank you for suggestion. Can you please help me with the selection between 2 SSDs I mentioned. I just want to be sure that if "WD green" can work with my machine then Samsung's EVO 860 will also work and their internal implementation wouldn't make any issue in compatibility. I want to go with Evo 860.

Comment: @Yadvendra - Questions seeking hardware recommendations are out of scope here at Super User.  Since your laptop will support any M.2 SATA drive you should have no problem selecting a drive that your laptop supports. Your putting to much weight into a customer support agent who copied and pasted answers from a script that contained inaccurate answers

Comment: @Ramhound ok, Thank you for the efforts.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your laptop is the 2017 model, in which case from a quick bit of googling, it looks like this only supports M.2 SSDs, not NVMe. You can quickly confirm this by looking at what PCIe version is supported, and what your link speed is.

You can use HWINFO64, then expand Bus, expand PCI Bus #0, highlight PCI Express Root Port, from looking around, it should be an Intel chipset, might be number #5, either way you'll notice it!

If that is the case, then you should be fine ideally to buy any M.2 SSD. It'll go at SATA speeds but it'll still be a hefty storage upgrade.

In my own personal experiences. I'm not aware of any storage restrictions that would be in action. Especially not 512gb. At the end of the day, the port does not care about the capacity of the drive. Acer has just told you what their system can be configured up to.

You should be able to easily install an M.2 SSD of any capacity in that slot.

Comment: Did you perhaps accidentally switch words? A NVMe SSD is typically also using an M.2 connector. If the connector only does SATA, he precisely needs a SATA M.2 SSD. Also with the correct key (B/M).

Comment: There are 3 PCI Express Root Port each with following:
1. PCI Version: 3.0 Max Link Speed: 8.0 GT/S Max Link Width: 2x
2. PCI Version: 3.0 Max Link Speed: 8.0 GT/S Max Link Width: 1x
3. PCI Version: 3.0 Max Link Speed: 8.0 GT/S Max Link Width: 1x

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, in the case of SATA, as opposed to the case of NVMe, there won't be a vendor/model "whitelist" in the UEFI firmware, let alone capacity limitation (especially when consumer-grade SSDs are still somewhat capped at 2T).

With that said though, while most "technical support" are just cheap labour that copy and paste and/or "deduce" (guess) from information / specification that is false / ambiguous to them, it's kind of hard to tell how pathetic a firmware / how sick a vendor could be.